# Basic doubt in OR operator

Tags: sql

Hi All:
I am rourke to SQL and here is my doubt is using OR operator. I have an employee table with 2 records, employeeid column  of 1st row value is 1 and 2nd row column value is *. My query has to fetch the row with employeeid column value as 1 otherwise it has to fetch the rows with employeeid as *. Finally the query has to fetch either one set of records i.e. set of records with employeeid as 1 or set of records with employeeid as *. 
I  have used "**Select * from Employee where emp_id = '1' or emp_id = '*';"** but the resultset is fetching all rows where employeeid value as 1 and *. I want either one set of records only.
 How to do it in SQL? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to have the row with `emp_id = '1'` but if it doesn't exist you want to have the row with `emp_id = '*'`?

Comment: OR means return all records which either match criterion 1 or match criterion 2, without preference.

Comment: Yes Howard.. That is the exact scenario i am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Employee 
 WHERE emp_id = '1' 
 UNION ALL
SELECT * 
    FROM Employee 
 WHERE emp_id = '*' 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1 
                FROM    Employee 
             WHERE emp_id = '1' 
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * 
from Employee 
where emp_id = case 
        when exists (select * from Employee where emp_id = '1') 
        then '1' 
        else '*' 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Employee where emp_id = '1'  OR emp_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from Employee where emp_id = '1' or emp_id = '*' order by emp_id desc
```